# IE11 onPaste Event triggered through execCommand("paste",...)

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, execcommand

I am trying to make some paste event listener that "clean" the input. Because of IE11 don't have execCommand("insertText",..) i use execCommand("paste",..) (for browsers, which don't have insertText). But somehow, in the execCommand("paste",..) makes the event paste triggered again.

Now, the question is, how to prevent paste event being triggered by execCommand("paste",...)?

Here is my current code:

```
function pasteHandler(e) {
    // cancel paste
    e.preventDefault();
    // get text representation of clipboard
    clipboard = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    var text;
    if (e.clipboardData){
        text = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
    }else if (window.clipboardData){
        text = window.clipboardData.getData("text");
    }   
    text = text.trim(); //example cleaning
    console.log(text);

    // insert text manually
    if (document.queryCommandSupported('insertText')) {
      document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
    } else {
      document.execCommand('paste', false, text);
    }
}

obj.addEventListener("paste", pasteHandler, false);
```

**Edit:**
The element i add the listener is :

```
<div contenteditable="true"> </div>
```

Comment: In what kind of element are you? Can't you just change its textContent / value?

Comment: @Kaiido updated the question. The element is div, and if i change the textContent, that means previous data in textContent is replaced entirely. I don't want that, so i use execCommand.

Comment: you could grab the TextNode the cursor is on (getSelection) and modify only this node's textContent. Should have the same endover as insertText. Would require some more processing if the range is open, but still probably doable.